# Update row data with id not carrying id forward

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

Have being trying this query for 3 days now. I have a list of rows here: http://prntscr.com/dick00. All what I want to is to edit and delete each row respectively. For some reason the id is not carrying forward and no record is updating.

When I click on edit in access.php I get `edit_access.php?id=` in address bar.

Here is my link in **access.php**

```
                  <td><a href="edit_access.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>edit</td>
```

**edit_access.php**
**EDIT 1: php code**

```
        <?php

    // start session
    session_start();
    //   error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    }

    // include connection
    require_once('include/connection.php');

    // set user session variables
    $userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $error = [] ;
    if(isset($_POST['update']))   
    {                 
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $therapist = $_POST['therapist'];
    $access_type = $_POST['access_type'];
    $code = $_POST['code']; 
    $created_at = $_POST['created_at'];        
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];  

    // validate form field
    if (empty($firstname)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter patient first name';        
                }
    if (empty($lastname)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter patient last name';        
                }

    if (empty($therapist)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your name';                      
                 // $error = true;
                }
    if (empty($code)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter patient access code';                      
                 // $error = true;
                } 
     if (empty($access_type)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please check access type';                      
                 // $error = true;
                } 
      if (empty($postcode)){     
                  $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter patient postcode';                      
                 // $error = true;
                } 



            //if no errors have been created carry on
    if(empty($error)){         

    $updated_at = date('Y-m-d');
    // ************* UPDATE PROFILE INFORMATION ************************//
    if(!($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE access SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?, therapist = ?, access_type = ?, postcode = ?, code = ?, updated_at = ?
    WHERE id = ?"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $con->errno . ")" . $con->error;
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssssssi', $firstname, $lastname, $therapist, $access_type, $postcode, $code, $updated_at, $userId)){
    echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
    }

    if($stmt) {
    $_SESSION['main_notice'] = '<div class="alert alert-success">"Access Code Added successfully!"</div>';
    header('Location: access.php');
    exit;

    }else{
        $_SESSION['main_notice'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">"Some error, try again"</div>';
        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    }                      

    }       


    // title page
    $title = "Edit Access Record | Allocation | The Whittington Center";

    // include header
    require_once('include/header.php');
    ?>

    <?php   
      if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      $userId = $_GET['id'];
      }
      else{ 
      $userId = $_POST['user_id'];

      //  mysqli_close($con);
      $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM access WHERE id = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();  
      if($stmt->num_rows == 0) {  
      echo 'No Data Found for this user';
      }else {
      $stmt->bind_result($firstname, $lastname, $therapist, $access_type, $postcode, $code);
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch());

      $stmt->close();

      }
    ?>
```

**EDIT 2: HTML part**

```
                    <h2 class="text-light text-greensea">Edit Access Record</h2>


                    <form name="access" class="form-validation mt-20" novalidate="" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" autocomplete='off'>


                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' firstname ']; } ?>' placeholder='firstname'></td>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' lastname ']; } ?>' placeholder='lastname'></td>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="therapist" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' therapist ']; } ?>' placeholder='therapist'></td>
                      </div>

                      <?php $access_type = $access_type; ?>
                      <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="work status">Access Type</label>
                        <div name="access_type" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' access_type ']; } ?>'>

                          <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-custom">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="access_type" <?php if (isset($work_status) && $access_type == "Keysafe") echo "checked"; ?> value="Keysafe"><i></i>Keysafe
                        </label>
                          <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-custom">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="access_type" <?php if (isset($access_type) && $access_type == "keylog") echo "checked"; ?> value="keylog"><i></i>Keylog
                        </label>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' code ']; } ?>' placeholder='access code'></td>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST[' postcode ']; } ?>' placeholder='postcode'></td>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group text-left mt-20">
                        <button type="update" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="update" id='update'>Add Access</button>
                        <!--                             <label class="checkbox checkbox-custom-alt checkbox-custom-sm inline-block">
            <input type="checkbox"><i></i> Remember me
        </label> -->
                        <a href="access.php">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-greensea b-0 br-2 mr-5">Back</button>
                        </a>
                      </div>

                    </form>



                </div>
                <!-- end of container -->
```

Thanks guy's for requesting for more code... i hope have given enough code sample.

Comment: can you explain more? in this code you are trying to update on row in database but you expect what?

Comment: The error is in `access.php`, but not on that line, you must show us more code. Basically, $row['id'] doesn't exist (it may be an error in the select query or in the php cycle)

Comment: i cannot under stand you...... do you have any form for updating this information? you must explain the problem instead of coping your code

Answer (score 0):

you most put your id inside of a hidden input in your html form like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="itemId" value="<?php echo '$_GET['id']'?>">`

and then when you submit your form you have **itemId** in side ***$_POST['itemId']*** variable.

EDIT:
I must describe scenario for you. maybe you got the point.
you have a list of access witch in every row has this tag:

```
<a href="access-form.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">access ....</a>
```

in your access-form.php you have a form with this structure:

```
<form method="post" action="edit-access.php">
    .....
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']?>">
    .....
</form>
```

next  in your edit-access.php you can access to this id by this syntax:

```
echo $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving a enough info code i will edit to reflect this. @Navid_pdp11... where do i put the hidden input, before submit or?

Comment: every where inside your edit panel.... beside your text boxes that contain name and other information about row

Comment: Hi did quite get tho... please check my updated code

Comment: inform me about result... and check as answered if you got the solution

Comment: i repeat it again..... please add hidden input inside your form witch you add inside your question

Comment: sorry for lack of understand have really come along way to understand php. so have added this `<?php if ($userId != '') { ?>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control underline-input" value='<?php echo $userId;  ?>' placeholder='firstname'></td>
                          </div>
<?php } ?>` above the firstname field in my edit_access.php HTML section. is that where he should be?

Comment: have added it, after submiting the form i get blank page and when i present return key again i get this http://prntscr.com/diipz5. no record was updated in the database

Comment: no different any where inside form tag. and then you have this filed in $_POST variable after submit. that's it. simple as so.